# how to write the mongodb code in delphi

Tags: delphi, mongodb

This is the original code I tried:

```
obj = {
    sentence:  "this is a sentece", 
    tags: [ "some", "indexing", "words"]     
}
```

and

```
findOne({tags: "words"}).name);
```

I used the **TMongWire** as the wrapper of MongoDB for Delphi
and I wrote this:

```
//var
//  d:IBSONDocument;
d:=BSON([
    'id',mongoObjectID,
    'sentence', 'this is a sentece',
    'tags','["some", "indexing", "words"]'
]);
FMongoWire.Insert(theCollection,d);
```

it seem the codes above do the work

---

but when I query with the 'tags', it seems to not work for me

```
//var 
//q:TMongoWireQuery;
//qb:IBSONDocument 
qb:=BSON(['tags', '"words"']); //***
q:=TMongoWireQuery.Create(FMongoWire);
q.Query(mwx2Collection, qb); //***
```

How do I write the two lines with *** asterisks?

Answer (score 6):

The error is not in the query, bit in the fields creation.

As you wrote it, you created the tags field as a string property, not an array of strings.

```
d:=BSON([
    'id',mongoObjectID,
    'sentence', 'this is a sentece',
    'tags',VarArrayOf(['some', 'indexing', 'words'])
]);
FMongoWire.Insert(theCollection,d);
```

You have to call `VarArrayOf()` to create an array of strings.

*Edited: introduced `VarArrayOf()`*

Comment: I would try passing a native Delphi `Array` type.  If that doesn't work, you could always post a [TMongoWire issue on github](https://github.com/stijnsanders/TMongoWire/issues) and hopefully the original author will respond / document what is required.

Comment: VarArrayOf() instead of BSONArray().... I was not far away from the definitive answer! :) OleVariant is somewhat time consuming, and platform dependent... native Delphi arrays could have made better sense.

Answer (score 3):

TMongoWire tries to use OleVariant to their full extent, so you pass arrays as variant arrays, e.g. using [VarArrayOf](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Variants.VarArrayOf):

```
FMongoWire.Insert(theCollection,BSON([
    'id',mongoObjectID,
    'sentence', 'this is a sentece',
    'tags',VarArrayOf(['some', 'indexing', 'words'])
]);
```

and there's no javascript notation parsing of strings, so write:

```
q.Query(mwx2Collection, BSON(['tags','words']));
```